# Apache2 - Error 403 forbidden

Tags: apache2, http-status-code-403

I develop projects that I've located in /home/user/projects directory. This directory is chmod 777. The problem is that I'm always getting Error 403 Forbidden when I try to access this directory or any subdirectory. This is how my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin user@user.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/projects

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    <Directory /> 
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/gtakacs/projects>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What's wrong with this? When I used /var/www as my document root, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : try doing `chmod -R 777 /home` to make sure all your home is available (note that this solution is NOT RECOMENDED, having your project in /var/www would definitely be a better solution in my opinion)

(Can't comment so post reply)

Isn't there a config file in your project where you're supposed to set who can access the app? Check if you didn't forget to add your ip adress and domain name in this file.

When using Apache2 with Django framework (python), I had the same error, and it was because I forgot to add the domain name to authorized hosts.

You can also check access.log and error.log to have more detailed informations on what caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

Command out:

```
#Order allow,deny
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, the problem might be that your document root does not contain the described directories.